# How to import nested library project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, facebook-sdk-3.0, android-simple-facebook

I'm following this github library: [android simple facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) and this is the wiki page: [setup project](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/wiki/Setup-project).

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 and i've got lot of troubles trying to follow first 3 steps of the guide. In particular this is what i do:

1) Create new project

2) Create folder libs at same level of .idea package

3) Put "Simple Facebook" library inside this folder

4) Add `compile project(':libs:Simple Facebook')` in `build.gradle`under app package

5) Add `include ':libs:Simple Facebook'` in settings.gradle

6) Create new folder libs inside Simple Facebook package

7) Put "facebook" library inside this folder

8) Add `compile project(':libs:facebook')` in `build.gradle`under Simple Facebook package

9) Add `include ':libs:facebook'` in settings.gradle

But what i have when i build project is: `cannot evaluate module simple facebook : configuration with name 'default' not found.`

There is someone who can explain me how to  import this library and Facebook SDK correctly? 
Thank you all.

Comment: I would try removing the space, so the directory is `SimpleFacebook` and not `Simple Facebook`, with corresponding changes in your `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` files. BTW, you did not mention changing `settings.gradle`, but you need for it to list all of the modules within the project.

Comment: I'll try your first suggestion... but i don't understand the second, what do you mean? My idea was to  include "SimpleFacebook" in App settings.gradle and "facebook" in "SimpleFacebook" settings.gradle.

Comment: "My idea was..." -- that may work. I haven't played with this sort of nesting before. If it doesn't work, have everything be referenced in the top-level `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Nothing.. i'm still have the same error.. i've tried all the possibilities.. any help?